# Multiple accounts creation at a time

Tags: php

I am trying to build an application, which could create multiple accounts at the same time. For example I add single account using ....

```
 $data = array('username'=>$username, 'email'=>$email, 'active'=>$active, 'admin'=>$admin);
 $add_user->AddUser($data);
```

Should I use explode method? How do I provide multiple values like username, email etc. Please help...

Comment: Why don't you just call `AddUser()` multiple times with different arrays?

Comment: @alex yes i can, but how can i provide values for multilple action?

Answer (score 0):

**call AddUser for each addition**, or make data a nested array.

```
 $data = array(
array('username'=>$username, 'email'=>$email, 'active'=>$active, 'admin'=>$admin),
array('username'=>$username2, 'email'=>$emai2, 'active'=>$active2, 'admin'=>$admin2)
)
```

and then execute each of them .

But I would **call AddUser for each addition**